# Wifi get disconnected in ubuntu 20.4 lts

Tags: wireless

I recently installed ubuntu 20.4 on my laptop. Tjis is the first time I am using a linux distribution. After installing i am facing wifi discontinution problem. My wifi get disconnected almost immediately after connecting it. I tried every solution I found in internet. My wifi interface is wlp3s0

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list` terminal command. All solutions are hardware specific. How could you try any solution if you didn't know what is the hardware?

Comment: Its look like my hardware is Ralink corp. RT3090 Wireless 802.11n 1T/1R PCIe

Comment: Kernel driver in use ; rt2800pci,  kernel modules are same. Nothing is blocked.

Comment: Pilot 06 if these information is enough then please help me.